# How to set the limit in the findone method

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

```
async hospitalImages(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let hospital_id = req.params.id;
        let hospital_images = await Hospital.findOne({
            attributes: ["id"],
            where: { id: hospital_id },
            include: [
                { 
                    model: Image,
                    as: "Image",
                    attributes: ["id", "image"],
                },
            ],
        });
        res.status(200).json(hospital_images);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Request can't be processed" });
    }
}
```

In this code Im getting multiple images.how to set limit for this,perticularly  in findOne method.

Comment: Are you using mongodb? Maybe share the import section of the file as well to understand better

Comment: Im using mysql (sequalize orm)

Comment: im getting multiple hospital images in the findOne method...i dont no how to set the limit for findOne method

Comment: As such findOne should return one record only. Also as per sequalize document, "The findOne method obtains the first entry it finds (that fulfills the optional query options, if provided)." Check here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html

Comment: yes sir....but in my project Im getting multiple records is there in findOne method.. In raw query(sql query) taking the limit....in code didn' take limit